# Having hard time where to put CFRelease calls

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks

I'm having a hard time where to put my `CFRelease()` calls in the below code. Either if I put my `CFRelease()` inside one bracket it will complain missing in another bracket.

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

if (phones == nil || ABMultiValueGetCount(phones) == 0) {

    CFArrayRef linkedContacts = ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople(person);
    phones = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    for (int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(linkedContacts); i++) {

        ABRecordRef linkedContact = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(linkedContacts, i);
        ABMultiValueRef linkedPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(linkedContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        if (linkedPhones != nil && ABMultiValueGetCount(linkedPhones) > 0) {

            for (int j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(linkedPhones); j++) {

                ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phones, ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(linkedPhones, j), NULL, NULL);
            }
        }
    }

    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phones) == 0) {

        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably know, you have to release all objects that you "own", i.e. all objects
returned from a function with "Create" or "Copy" in the name, *but only* if the call
succeeded. If the functions returns `NULL`, you must not call `CFRelease` on the returned value.

For example, in your code

```
ABMultiValueRef linkedPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(linkedContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
if (linkedPhones != nil && ABMultiValueGetCount(linkedPhones) > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

is is unclear whether to call `CFRelease(linkedPhones)` at the end of the if-block or not.
It might be better to check separately if a call succeeded or not.

So that part of your code would look like:

```
ABMultiValueRef linkedPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(linkedContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
if (linkedPhones != nil) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(linkedPhones); j++) {
        CFTypeRef value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(linkedPhones, j);
        if (value != nil) {
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phones, value, NULL, NULL);
            CFRelease(value);
        }
    }
    CFRelease(linkedPhones);
}
```

I hope that will get you started to rewrite your complete function Analyzer-safe!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: @PeterWarbo: You are welcome. I was too lazy to "fix" the entire function, but please feel free to ask for more information if necessary!